# Keras :valueerror:cannot reshape array of size 4096 into shape (1,64,64,3)

Tags: python, keras, opencv

**I am taking image for webcamp using cv2**
I trained a model using the ASL dataset, and I am going to classify an image from webcamp.  For this I need to resize the image according to the trained model.

It says I have to convert the webcamp image to have a shape of (1, 64, 64, 3) but it's giving me an error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import imutils
from numpy import array

model = load_model('trained_model2.h5')
print('model loaded!')
out_label=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y']

pre = []
s = ''
cchar = [0, 0]
c1 = ''    
aWeight = 0.5    
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    
top, right, bottom, left = 170, 150, 425, 450    
num_frames = 0    
flag = 0
flag1=  0

while capture.isOpened():
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=700)

    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    clone = frame.copy()

    (height, width) = frame.shape[:2]

    roi = frame[top:bottom, right:left]
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
    
    img = gray
    
    IMG_SIZE = 64
    
    img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    data = img.reshape(1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
    print("converted")
         
    data = data / 255
   
    model_out = model.predict([data][0])
    pnb = np.argmax(model_out)
    print(str(np.argmax(model_out)) + " " + str(out_label[pnb]))
    pre.append(out_label[pnb]) 

    cv2.putText(clone,
           '%s ' % (str(out_label[pnb])),
           (450, 150), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 5, (0, 255, 0))
    
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (100, 100), (300, 300), (0, 255, 0), 0)
    crop_image = frame[100:300, 100:300]
    
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(crop_image, (3, 3), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([2, 0, 0]), np.array([20, 255, 255]))
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5))  
    dilation = cv2.dilate(mask2, kernel, iterations=1)
    erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, kernel, iterations=1)
    filtered = cv2.GaussianBlur(erosion, (3, 3), 0)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(filtered, 127, 255, 0)
    
    cv2.imshow("Gesture", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Thresholded", thresh)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
    
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reshape a 4096-dimensional image to an image having the shape of (64, 64, 3) -- which denotes an image with RGB color (or BGR color in OpenCV). However, the images being read are grayscale. This means you should not reshape it to (64, 64, 3) but instead to (64, 64, 1).

```
data = img.reshape(1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```